# Vspace after amsmath aligned equation gets ignored

Tags: amsmath

In the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    $\begin{aligned}
        A &B C \\
        D &E F
    \end{aligned}$ \\
    \vspace{2in} Vspace gets ignored.
\end{document}
```

The manually added `\vspace` after the equation gets ignored.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're doing several things wrong; regarding the `\vspace` issue, `\vspace{2in}` will only be applied at the end of the line.

Comment: If you want a space after the equations, use ``\\[2in]``, but this way of typing things is wrong: a display should be centered.

Comment: @egreg I'm building a math test, so the layout is rather different from normal standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not ignored but a `\vspace` in horizontal mode(as here) adds space after the current line after the paragraph is broken into lines, so after `ignored` in this case.

To see the space compare your example with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    $\begin{aligned}
        A &B C \\
        D &E F
    \end{aligned}$ \\
    \vspace{2in} Vspace gets ignored.

see?
\end{document}
```

In this case it would seem that `align` is more suitable than `aligned` as it makes the math display set off by suitable vertical space.

Answer (score 7):

If you want a space after the display, use `\\[<dimen>]`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    $\begin{aligned}
        A &B C \\
        D &E F
    \end{aligned}$ \\[2in]
    Vspace doesn't get ignored.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

no one has yet come up with the "obvious" solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    $\begin{aligned}
        A &B C \\
        D &E F
    \end{aligned}$ \par
    \vspace{2in} Vspace is not ignored.
\end{document}
```

`\vspace` acts immediately only in vertical mode.